# How can I turn on compression for my IIS 7 web sites?

Tags: iis

I am using IIS7 and trying to optimize as much as possible. I had one suggestion about compression but I am not sure how to turn this on. I am familiar with making changes to Web.Config but not sure about making IIS7 changes. What makes it more difficult is that I am using Windows Azure where new images are created every time I publish.

Can someone explain if there's more than one way to turn on compression and how I can do it.

Answer (score 3):

[Configuring HTTP Compression in IIS 7](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc730629%28WS.10%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks John. I also found the following which I think will help me: http://blog.smarx.com/posts/iis-compression-in-windows-azure